# How to offer calls over HTTPS exclusively

Tags: php, https

I'm writing some APIs for another website to be able to interact with my website. They say this in their documentation:

> All calls made over HTTPS.

I don't know what that means for me on my end.  Does it just mean I need to be hosted on a

```
httpS://www.mywebsite.com
```

page instead of

```
http://www.mywebsite.com
```

What do I need to do on my end (PHP based code) to accept "calls over https".

I don't need any code written or anything like that, I just need to understand the scope of what I'm trying to do. Is it my code that deciphers the HTTPS call? Is it the server that I'm hosted on?  What does this mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an SSL certificate installed on your server, which you can get from a Certificate Authority like Thawte or Verisign.  Once that is done, your site will be able to serve the same content over `https://...` and `http://...`

You can then restrict it via the webserver's configuration to only allow the `https://....` (simplest thing to do).  Or you can leave it at the default which will allow both, and you can make a determination in the particular script being called whether it will accept both or only one or the other.

But for simplicity (especially when you really don't understand the concept of SSL as to when you should use it or don't really have to) you probably ought to just restrict your webserver to serve only `https://...` How you do that depends on whether you are using IIS or Apache HTTPD, etc.

Comment: Ok. Just so I understand, I think you are saying, I need to be hosted on a site that offers a SSL certificate so when you come to my site you go to https://  once i'm working with a https:// site then calls made over https will work the same as normal calls on a normal site.  as far as the php code goes, nothing is different, its just whether or not my webserver allows the other site to send the requests or not.